# How to use Amazon MWS API

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I have used APIs that are hosted somewhere like Google custom search APi

However I need to use Amazon MWS API for next project.

As I searched on Google there is no hosted version and neither details about how to host one such.

Please guide me about using this API.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you mean about a "hosted" version, but everything related to Amazon MWS is locatated here: https://developer.amazonservices.com/

The developer guide: http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/index.html

The scratchpad: http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/scratchpad/index.html

The seller forums:  https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=35&start=0

Answer (score 0):

So, first off you are not alone. Trying to figure this out has drove me nuts.
I am pretty new to programming and web apps.

You need a Professional Selling Account ($39.99/month)

https://developer.amazonservices.com/ --->> [Sign up or Manage MWS](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/account-manager/home.html)

You need to register as a developer as well.

You are looking for "Client Library".[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0pj6.png)

There is a different library for each of the APIs and their respective languages.

You must be logged in to view the libraries i believe